# Cordova - hide loading screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

In my Cordova/Ionic app, when I open it, for a few milliseconds appears a loading screen (look the image), then the splashscreen and then the app.
How can I hide it and show immediately the splashscreen?

[image]